# Calculating time complexity of a recursive function having a loop inside it

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I was working on a simple problem and I came up with a recursive function in C++, below is my function.

```
void test(int arr[],int n,int x = 0){
    cout<<arr[x];
    for(int i = x+1;i < n;i++){
        test(arr, n, i);
    }
}
```

I wonder what will be the time complexity of the above function if anyone can calculate the time complexity for the above method it will be a great help in improving my function.

Comment: Recursion can be seens as a kind of fancy loop. So if you could rewrite the recursion into a loop then it might be easier.

Comment: Instead of `x = x + 1; test(arr, n, x);` why don't you just write `test(arr, n, i);`? It's equivalent, but simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: Can't we use any master theorem here??

Comment: This seems exponential complexity algorithm at first sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write its recurrent relation likes the following:

```
 T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + 1
```

Indeed `T'(x)` is `T(n - x)` and `T(1) = 1` (The last one in the realtion is is for `cout`). We can see:

```
T(2) = T(1) + 1 = 2
T(3) = T(2) + T(1) + 1 = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4
T(4) = 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 + 1 = 8
T(5) = 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 + 1 = 16
.
.
.
T(n) = 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1} + ... + 2^0 + 1 = 2^{n-1}
```

Hence, `T(n) = \Theta(2^n)`.

Comment: How you are using T(n-1) ?? It should be n+1 I guess?? If I am wrong please correct me

Comment: @MohdShibli As I said `T(n-1)` is time complexity for `x = 1` and generally, `T(i)` is for `x = n - i`.

Comment: Maybe the complexity will be O(k^n) as the loop will run k times for worst case